# Remove users from AD group using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, system-administration

I have created a short snippet that should remove members in a list from a specific AD group.

```
Remove-QADGroupMember -Identity "usergroup" -Member (Get-Content "C:\Users\blabla\users.txt")
```

The problem is that the list contains alot of old non-existing users. As soon as the script hits a invalid user it stops. Is there any way to have PS ignore users it cannot find without making this too complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try/catch in Powershell. It looks like:

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\blabla\users.txt" | foreach {
    Try {
        Remove-QADGroupMember -Identity "usergroup" -Member $_
    }
    Catch [System.Exception] {
        "$_ isn't exit"
    }
}
```

I didn't run the code. You can do some tuning on it.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx is a good post on this topic.

Comment: This seems to work! I'll make sure to read up on the topic. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, because I needed to remove all the users for a bunch of groups rather than a user list.

- Finds me the groups that were setup for a project

  `$OldGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "<*ProjectName>"}`
- Clears the **`Members`** property of the group effectively removing all the users

  `$OldGroups | foreach {Set-ADGroup $_ -Clear Member}`